# How to apply color to only part of a SVG icon with CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

Here I have this font color picker icon using a svg icon. When a specific color is selected, I want to change the bottom rectangle (not the A letter) to match the selected color, so I am wondering if there is a way to only render the bottom part of the svg icon with specific color?

[image]

[image]

Below is the SVG code:

```html
<svg class="svgIcon---svg---3eBcz" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8 1c.2 0 .38.12.46.3l3 7a.5.5 0 01-.92.4L9.81 7H6.2l-.73 1.7a.5.5 0 11-.92-.4l3-7A.5.5 0 018 1zM6.62 6h2.76L8 2.77 6.62 6zM2 11.5c0-.83.67-1.5 1.5-1.5h9c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5v2c0 .83-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 012 13.5v-2z"></path></svg>
```

Is it possible to change some numbers in the svg path or add a specific fill-rule so that only the bottom part could be filled with color, or, is there another way to do that with only CSS change?

Below is how it looks like with the outer HTML document. I am only given the option to modify the css styles on the **i** (icon) element.

```html
<i data-icon-name="TextColorFilled" aria-hidden="true" class="Button-icon icon-518"><span role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" class="svgIcon---root---V-j2a" style="vertical-align: top; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
<svg class="svgIcon---svg---3eBcz" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M8 1c.2 0 .38.12.46.3l3 7a.5.5 0 01-.92.4L9.81 7H6.2l-.73 1.7a.5.5 0 11-.92-.4l3-7A.5.5 0 018 1zM6.62 6h2.76L8 2.77 6.62 6zM2 11.5c0-.83.67-1.5 1.5-1.5h9c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5v2c0 .83-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 012 13.5v-2z"></path>
</svg>
</span>
</i>
```

Comment: Give it an id or class name. It works the same as HTML

Comment: Hmm.. weirdly it is only a single path. Is the `A` part of the icon? When I said give it an id or class name I meant you could do `<path class="redrect" d="...`

Comment: How is your SVG incorporated into your HTML document? Is this an inline `<svg>`-in-HTML5, or as an `<img />`, or is this SVG loaded into a CSS `background-image`?

Comment: I think you’ll have to split the path into two so you can color them separately.

Comment: @Dai It is an inline svg, which is wrapped by <i> element, I just updated the question with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you split the svg into two paths you can select the second one and color just that using fill and CSS.

```html
<style>
path:nth-child(2) {
  fill: red;
}
</style>
<svg class="svgIcon---svg---3eBcz" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M8 1c.2 0 .38.12.46.3l3 7a.5.5 0 01-.92.4L9.81 7H6.2l-.73 1.7a.5.5 0 11-.92-.4l3-7A.5.5 0 018 1zM6.62 6h2.76L8 2.77 6.62 6z"></path>
<path d="M2 11.5c0-.83.67-1.5 1.5-1.5h9c.83 0 1.5.67 1.5 1.5v2c0 .83-.67 1.5-1.5 1.5h-9A1.5 1.5 0 012 13.5v-2z"></path></svg>
```

Comment: ah it works! I got your point. So, shall I directly apply this css style to the svg element? The thing is, in the existing code, I am only given the option to apply css style to the i element, which is something like <i><span><svg>....</svg></span></i>, would this work as well?

Comment: Doesn't the `<style>` need to live within the `<svg>` element, though? I'm not sure all browsers let a HTML-scoped `<style>` apply to inner `<svg>` elements - I'd love to be wrong on this though.

Comment: @Dai That's a good idea! If <style> lives with <svg>, I am wondering how we can specify the color for the fill property from outside. Since the color could be changed dynamically, we cannot hard code it in advance.

Comment: @flyingbee You can probably hack it together by using JS to set a CSS custom-property inside the SVG scope (e.g. `path:nth-child(2) { fill: var(--my-color); }`.

Comment: @dai CSS tricks has an article on the presentation properties that can be applied via CSS. https://css-tricks.com/svg-properties-and-css/  I have never heard of a modern browser not allowing this on path elements but may of course have missed something.

Comment: @flyingbee I’m not quite sure I understand what you mean by only being given the option of styling the i element. Could you expand on what limitations you are being set?

Comment: @AHaworth My remark wasn't about `<path>` not being supported - my remark was about me not knowing if browsers will allow a `--custom-property` set in a HTML document to be used from within a nested `<svg>` image.

Comment: @dai ah, do you mean if the style is set in a style sheet using a CSS variable will the path use it?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes, but more specifically: not the _style_ or style-style itself, just the cascading custom-property.

Comment: @dai seems to work fine in my tests (Chrome/edge)

Comment: @AHaworth In the real code, I only have access to the parent element of the SVG element (which is an icon element), so I am not sure if I can directly apply the style as what you did to the SVG. I was wondering if I can somehow apply the style to its parent element and get it working. Anyway, your answer is very helpful!